# cannot restart app in openshift after updated gem

Tags: git, openshift, application-restart, openshift-client-tools

I couldn't restart my app via rhc restart {myapp} after run gem updating. I ran:

*rhc restart-app* {myapp}

Then they asked me for password.

after typed the password, I see:

*Unable to authenticate the user. Please try again and contact support if the issue persists.
Reference ID: (A string)*

How can I fix it? I also get this error when try to type *rhc tail {myapp}* and cannot see the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were experiencing an issue with authentication that should be resolved by now. Can you try it again and if it fails, paste in the error with the reference ID.